# ES6 with default arguments : Whether a parameter is passed in or not

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, default-parameters

```
function myfunc( value1, value2='defaultValue' ) {
  //some stuff
}
```

How will I know that if a parameter is passed in or not into a function. I know that the default value will be set if you don't pass in anything as argument.I actually want to check if the user is passing anything as a 2nd parameter ( even if it is same as the default value ) and change my return value accordingly.

I was checking out [ES6 docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461428/check-if-argument-is-passed-to-a-java-script-function) , Not really what I am looking for.

Thanks,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`arguments` still represents the actual arguments you were sent, so `arguments.length` will give you that information.

```js
function myfunc( value1, value2='defaultValue' ) {
  console.log("value1", value1);
  console.log("value2", value2);
  console.log("length", arguments.length);
}
myfunc("foo");
```

On a compliant JavaScript engine, that outputs

```
value1 foo
value2 defaultValue
length 1
```

`arguments` will not work in an arrow function, though, and [estus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3731501/estus) posted [a good alternative that does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40790191/157247).

Answer (score 5):

For complex parameter processing rest parameter may be beneficial, also deprecates `arguments.length`:

```js
function myfunc(...args) {
  let [value1, value2 = 'defaultValue'] = args;

  console.log("value1", value1);
  console.log("value2", value2);
  console.log("args.length", args.length);
}
myfunc("foo");
```

Manual arguments parsing is particularly useful for the cases with intuitive approach to defaults, i.e. when passed argument should replace default value even if it is `undefined`:

```
function myfunc(...args) {
  const defaultArgs = ['defaultValue1', 'defaultValue2'];
  let [value1, value2] = Object.assign(defaultArgs, args);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Excellent option, and has the advantage of working in an arrow function (which `arguments` will not).

Comment: That's correct, inconsistency between arrow and regular functions is very good reason to choose common denominator (rest). To make the things worse, `arguments` is delayed-action bomb, it will work in arrows in transpiled code and some native implementations but will break in other native implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an unforgeable token as the default argument value. No caller will ever be able to pass this value as an argument, so'defaultValue' you *know* that the only way that the parameter can end up being bound to this particular value is that no argument was passed.

Thankfully, ECMAScript has a datatype for unforgeable tokens that does *exactly* what we want: [`Symbol`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-symbol-objects):

```
const myfunc = (() => {
    const value2Token = Symbol("value2");
    return function myfunc(value1, value2 = value2Token) {
        if (value2 === value2Token) { value2 = 'defaultValue'; }
        // some stuff
    }
})();
```

This is of course somewhat ugly, but I would contend that it is less ugly than messing with `arguments`, and it is a sure way of knowing *exactly* whether an optional argument was passed or not, since `Symbol`s are completely unforgeable.