# JavaScript RegEx - prevent from capturing if inside string

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following code with a textarea covering the left half side and a div covering the right half side. Whatever is inserted on the left gets copied to the right with the HTML tags (`<...>`) colored in brown.

The issue I have is how to make it so that if the tag is inside quotation marks or apostrophes (turning it into a string instead) it doesn't get captured by the RegEx pattern in the replace method (doesn't turn brown).

To explain it better, put the following text inside the code snippet's textarea:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      function getString() {
        return "This string's content contains a tag \"<>\" which isn't suppost to be captured by the RegEx pattern in the replace method";
      }
    </script>
  </head>
</html>
```

```js
function HtmlEncode(s) {
  let el = document.createElement("div");
  el.innerText = el.textContent = s;
  s = el.innerHTML;
  return s;
}
function textarea_oninput() {
  let text = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0].value;
  text = HtmlEncode(text);
  document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = text.replace(/&lt;(.*?(?=(?:&gt;)))&gt;/g, "<span style=\"color: rgb(155, 112, 63)\">&lt;$1&gt;</span>");
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
}
textarea {
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border-color: red;
  color: lightGray;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0;
  position: fixed;
  resize: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(50% - 0px);
}
div {
  background: rgb(20, 20, 20);
  border: 1px solid green;
  color: lightGray;
  font-family: monospace;
  height: calc(100% - 4px);
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px;
  outline: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px 0px 0px 2px;
  position: fixed;
  resize: none;
  white-space: pre;
  width: calc(50% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<textarea oninput="textarea_oninput()" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
<div></div>
```

Making the RegEx pattern something like `/"|'.+tag.+"|'/` isn't enough because there's `\"`, `\'`, `'` inside a string with `"`, `"` inside a string with `'` and possibly more that I'm missing to take into account.

Comment: input and output example? I put this one `<a>aasdas</a>
"<b>aasds</b>"` and the "b" example is in brown

Comment: Input: `<script>var str1 = " ' < \" ' > ' \' "; var str2 = ' " < \" ' > ' \' ';</script>`. Output is only the script tags being colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to match literal strings earlier than HTML tags:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].innerHTML = text.replace(/"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"|'[^'\\]*(?:\\.[^\\']*)*'|&lt;((?:.(?!&lt;))*)&gt;/g, function(match, p1) {
    return p1 ? "<span style=\"color: rgb(155, 112, 63)\">&lt;" + p1 + "&gt;</span>" : match;
});
```

*Note: catastrophic backtracking is probable.*

Comment: That's as confusing as I expected (seeing the result without making it myself bit by bit) but it seems to work as intended so thank you. I will try to learn it.

Comment: Added a [`?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark) in the 3th alternative `&lt;((?:.(?!&lt;))*?)&gt;` to make the `*` quantifier non-greedy and changed the return condition to [`p1 !== undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11461482/7393973) so it distinguishes when the argument `p1` is passed or when it's empty `""`, coloring `<>`.

Comment: Why did you made quantifier non-greedy?

Comment: `<<>>` gets fully colored if greedy and only `<<>` if non-greedy which is how the notepad++ works (which is where I'm copying the syntax highlighting from).

Comment: In your question you talked about HTML tags. What does `<<>>` have to do with HTML tags?

Comment: Pretty much nothing, I'm just trying to do as close as I can to the [notepad++ HTML syntax highlighting](https://i.imgur.com/Q7cDv2Z.png).